# How to change Chapter title case to CHAPTER?

Tags: sectioning, capitalization, texpad

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{16}{16}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bahasai,english]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 0\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

I've tried with `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB}` it doesn't changed (BAB is indonesian word for chapter). Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the main language in the document is Indonesian, you should load `babel` as

```
\usepackage[english,bahasai]{babel}
```

This will use “Bab” instead of “Chapter”. Now the problem is typesetting the name in uppercase letters: use `\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}` in the redefined code for `\@makechapterhead`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[
  left=3cm,
  top=3cm,
  right=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  bindingoffset=0.5cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,bahasai]{babel} % <---- main language last

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{16}{16}\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Large\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space \thechapter % <--- uppercase
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 0\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

Don't load both `sectsty` and `titlesec`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can see a simple example I made to make the Chapter label being UPPERCASE.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
   [display] %possible values are hang, leftmargin, drop, etc.
   {\Huge} % format to be applied to the whole title
   {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter} %label setting
   {0pt} %horizontal separation between label and title body
   {\MakeUppercase} %code preceding the title body
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB} %to change "chapter" into "bab"
\begin{document}
   \chapter{Preface}
   \section{Introduction}
   \section{Preliminary}
\end{document}
```

All I said is in `titlesec` package documentation. Go [here](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) for other explanation about formatting title.

Answer (score 0):

Please place `\renewcommand{\chaptername}` after `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{16}{16}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bahasai,english]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{BAB}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Large\bfseries \chaptername\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 0\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\chapter{Test}

Trial

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried your setup I think the problem from using babel into my language.